# Installing Google Drive on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I was searching for google drive and its installation instructions in ubuntu 12.04, I tried sudo apt -get install , but didn't find google drive application on  ubuntu repo. Is there any alternative or hack to install google drive on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: thanks for the info and I will try to use grive for my current ubuntu version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already know, Google (probably hates Linux users) does not provide a Linux client for its awesome Google Drive cloud storage service. But don't worry, as the open source community has its geniuses like Lorenzo Breda, who developed an unofficial Google Drive client for Linux, called Grive.

**Adding the PPA Repository**

This is an easy step, which requires you to open a Terminal by searching it in the Unity Dash or by pressing the CTRL+ALT+T key combination, and to paste the following code in the Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
```

Hit the Enter key, type your password when asked, and hit Enter again when asked if you want to add the repository. Do not close the Terminal.

**Installing Grive Tools and Grive**

Now, paste the following commands in the Terminal window, one by one, hitting enter after each one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y grive-tools
```

Once installed, search the application on the Unity Dash by typing Grive, and open it. The application will ask for your password, so insert it and click OK, and then it will start to download and configure the latest version of the Grive application, which will take some time.

Comment: is grive an authentic in terms of sending data as I cannot compromise with some of the files i store on google drive

Comment: Grive is open source, you can look for yourself.

Comment: There is no grive-tools package in that respiratory.

Answer (score -1):

When I was on my google drive account, it prompted me to install google drive. I clicked it and everything went smooth. It was kind of pointless though because when I clicked on the google docs icon, all it did was direct me to the google docs webpage. So im not sure if it is even worth your time.

Comment: nice one, brother!