# How to remove Google Drive from Ubuntu

Tags: software-uninstall, google-drive

Can you tell me the command lines for removing Google Drive from Ubuntu?

I don't find it very useful since it doesn't sync for some reason, I would rather use internet version only.

I've used [Installing Google Drive on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439777/installing-google-drive-on-ubuntu-12-04) as a guide to install it.

Answer (score 6):

Open a terminal and enter the following commands:

```bsh
sudo apt-get remove grive-tools
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
```